# Can you recommend books on WW2 Allied conferences?

Tags: world-war-two, international-relations, allies

Are there recommended books that analyze and present a history of the Allied conferences of WW2? I looked at the references here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_history_of_World_War_II and a lot were out of print. https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/wiki/books/wwii doesn't have a section on this topic.

I am aware some primary sources are public, like https://bookstore.gpo.gov/products/quadrant-conference-august-1943 but I would prefer some context and analysis.

[https://www.amazon.com/Important-Meetings-Allies-during-World/dp/1537069128](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1537069128) would be a good start, but this looks to be the amazon version of clickbait.

Thank you

Comment: Question about reference books are off-topic here.

Comment: Advocating Overlord by Philip Padgett, Potomac Books is very good. While it doesn't focus directly on the conferences, they figure very heavily in the narrative. Similarly Masters and Commanders by Andrew Roberts, Harper Perennial which focuses on Churchill, Roosevelt, Marshall and Brooke and their interactions.

Comment: Churchill talked a fair bit about all of them in his autobiography of WWII.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not all of the Inter-Allied Conferences, but some mostly relating to the combined chiefs of staff can be found in the CARLS digital library, for examples:

[Sextant conference, November-December 1943: papers and minutes of meetings, Sextant and Eureka conferences.](https://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p4013coll8/id/3691/rec/10)

[Octagon conference, September 1944: papers and minutes of meetings, Octagon conference and minutes of Combined Chiefs of Staff, meetings in London, June 1944.](https://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p4013coll8/id/3689/rec/14)

[Argonaut conference, January-February 1945: papers and minutes of meetings, Argonaut conference.](https://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p4013coll8/id/3687/rec/15)

[Trident conference, May 1943: papers and minutes of meetings.](https://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p4013coll8/id/3693/rec/16)

And a few [more here](https://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p4013coll8/search/searchterm/Meetings/field/keywor/mode/exact/conn/and)